# Why apple recommend the leading or trailing constrain to margins?

Tags: ios

In storyboard, when I pin my custom label .For example, the leading constraint is 10. However ,there exists 8pt margin. So we can see the origin of the label is (10+8,y).But for IOS7 and former , there is not exist the layout margin...So to make all the devices have the same look.We usually  use the follow code..

`[something setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];`

to cancel the margin ...
I thinks it very unnecessary..
so in fact , when I  pin the leading constraint,I always uncheck 'constraint to margins'

Am I right? Any idea of the layout margin?

[image]